# Insert multiplication sign between parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, multiplication, parentheses

Suppose you have the following string:

> 5+5(5)

I want to insert a multiplication sign between the 5 and (5)

> 5+5*(5)

Now also suppose you have the following other possibility:

> 5+(5)(5)

I want to insert a multiplication sign between the (5) and (5)

> 5+(5)*(5)

My attempt:

```
import re

ex1 = '4+6.9(39.3)(-2.3)(5+4)'

def convert(string):

  return re.sub(r"((?:\d+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]\w*\(\w+\)))((?:[a-zA-Z]\w*)|\()", r"\1*\2", string)

print(convert(ex1))
```

> 4+6.9*(39.3)(-2.3)(5+4)

This code only adds a multiplication to the first instance.

If the string is:

```
ex2 = '5(5)+5(5)+5(5)'
```

> 5*(5)+5*(5)+5*(5)

The code works for numbers before a parenthesis.

**How can I modify the code to include closed parenthesis before an open one?**

Comment: Use `string = re.sub(r'(?<!\*)\(', '*(', string)`

Comment: Should this work with nested parenthesis?

Comment: @timgeb I'm not sure I can think of an expression where `)(` wouldn't mean `)*(` nesting or not...

Comment: @anubhava One thing, negative lookbehind would insert the `*` before open parenthesis even if it is on the beginning of the string, that is why I went with positive that looks for close parenthesis or number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use positive lookbehind:

```
import re

a = '4+6.9(39.3)(-2.3)(5+4)'

print(re.sub('(?<=\d|\))(\()', '*(', a))
#4+6.9*(39.3)*(-2.3)*(5+4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you need to insert '*' sign wherever '(' appears?

If this is the case, this will give you what you need:

```
ex1 = '4+6.9(39.3)(-2.3)(5+4)'
print(''.join(['*' + x if x == '(' else x for x in ex1]))
#4+6.9*(39.3)*(-2.3)*(5+4)
```